Relationship between intraclass correlation and analysis of variance
I have a set of 16 human heights, half of which are from males, and half from
females.
















Males
164
182
179
170
166
178
169
180


Females
168
154
166
159
152
161
169
171



If I code sex as 0 for female and 1 for male, the interclass correlation
between height and sex is 0.64. This means r² = 0.41. I understand this to mean
that the variance of height in the full sample (79 cm²) can be broken down into

between-sex variance 0.41 × 79 = 32 cm², and
within-sex variance (1-0.41) × 79 = 47 cm².

I am trying to get a better intuition for analysis of variance, so I am reading Fisher's 1925 Statistical Methods for Research Workers. In it, he shows how to break down variation into components more directly through an identity
involving the sum of squares of deviations:




Deg. of Freedom
Sum of sq.
Mean sq.




Within-sex
14
698
50


Between-sex
1
484
484


Total
15
1182
79



Then, as far as I understand, Fisher claims that given the between-sex SSE and the total mean square s², we can solve r out of
484 = ns²(1 + (k-1)r)
which is
484 = 2×79×(1 + 7r)
which gives us r = 0.29. (I also get something similar to this when I ask R to produce pairs of measurements and compute the correlation from those.)
This seems to imply that the interclass correlation is a whopping 0.64, while the intraclass correlation is a lower 0.29.
I'm okay with this, because Fisher explains the intraclass correlation as equivalent to the
correlation between all pairs of subjects within each group, i.e. all males
paired up with all other males, and all females paired up with all other
females. It would make sense that the intraclass correlation is lower, because knowing the height of another member of the same class tells us less than
knowing the class, because we could get an unlucky member which is not
indicative of the main distribution of the class itself.
But, to my question: why is there this disparity between interclass correlation and intraclass correlation in how they split up the variance? From the interclass correlation we had

between-sex variance 0.41 × 79 = 32 cm², and
within-sex variance (1-0.41) × 79 = 47 cm².

but the intraclass correlation, which Fisher emphasises better represents analysis of variance, we get

within-sex variance 0.3 × 79 = 23 cm², and
between-sex variance (1-0.3) × 79 = 56 cm².

These are somewhat numbers, and it seems like they aren't quite representing the same thing. So what are these numbers representing, and why are they different from each other?
I have talked to an acquaintance about this but they can only say that interclass and intraclass correlations measure different things, they are unable to point to the incorrect mental leap I'm making when I assume both tell apart between-sex variance and within-sex variance. I'm turning to you in the hopes of getting more assistance with that.

I am feeling a little embarassed at this point. I made a tonne of mistakes in my calculations (the curious may wish to read through my edits to the original question) but in the end, once I had the calculations down, the only difference in the question seems to be down to the small sample size of data I started with.
If I generate large amounts of synthetic data, the two procedures outlined above (squared interclass correlation and intraclass correlation) break down variance explained by class belonging almost exactly equally.
Imagine I have spent days trying to understand this!
